# Howto fix the appearance order of the slices in a pie chart using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have for e.g. two data sets_s1_ and *s2*:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series(['Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female'])
s1.value_counts(normalize=True).plot.pie(autopct='%.1f %%', ylabel='', startangle=90)

s2 = pd.Series(['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male'])
s2.value_counts(normalize=True).plot.pie(autopct='%.1f %%', ylabel='', startangle=90)
```

Once I *show()* the plots, i get, that the type with the bigger percentage (in *s1* it is 'Female' and in *s2* it is 'Male') have the same color and it is the first element in counterclockwise direction. For visual comparison, I would like that the first slice will always be 'Female' and the second slice will always be 'Male' and of course the colors should be fix as well.

Is there a way to do it in pandas pie? or do i need to change to other library such as matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to put `sort_index` after `value_counts`. Safe fix is to concat two series and plot once:

```
pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1.value_counts(), 
              's2':s2.value_counts()}
            ).plot.pie(subplots=True)
```